# Export data to csv using wpdb database

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I want to export data of a sql table in csv. I am using the follwoing code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['export']))
{
          $file = 'email_csv'; // ?? not defined in original code
          $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `scholarship_uesr`;",ARRAY_A);

          if (empty($results)) {
            return;
          }

          $csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_keys($results[0])).'";'."\n";;

          foreach ($results as $row) {
            $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"',$row).'";'."\n";
          }
          $csv_output .= "\n";
          $dir = "/home/modifoun/public_html/wp-content/plugins/schloarship/menu-pages/csv/";
          $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";

          header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
          header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
          header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
          print $csv_output;
          exit;
        //  echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>Data Written to CSV File. <a href='".$geturl."' download>Click Here to Download</a></div>";
}
$allsubs = "SELECT * FROM `scholarship_uesr`";
$select_query = $wpdb->get_results($allsubs);
//echo $wpdb->last_error;
?>
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="export" class='btn btn-danger' value="Export Data to CSV !!!">
</form>
```

When I am using to this code then it is directly print the data of database instead of downloading the file.

When i turn on the `error_reporting` then it is throwing error :

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/modifoun/public_html/wp-admin/includes/template.php:2041) in /home/modifoun/public_html/wp-content/plugins/schloarship/menu-pages/student_list.php on line 45

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/modifoun/public_html/wp-admin/includes/template.php:2041) in /home/modifoun/public_html/wp-content/plugins/schloarship/menu-pages/student_list.php on line 46

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/modifoun/public_html/wp-admin/includes/template.php:2041) in /home/modifoun/public_html/wp-content/plugins/schloarship/menu-pages/student_list.php on line 47
```

How can I export data to csv using wordpress

Comment: I think the issue is that  `print $csv_output;`

You can read more here: https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-csv-file-using-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this before output has started. It looks like you have this in your template file?

Try adding this to your functions.php file.

```
add_action('init', 'exportCsv');
function exportCsv() {
  if(isset($_POST['export']))
  {
            $file = 'email_csv'; // ?? not defined in original code
            $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `scholarship_uesr`;",ARRAY_A);

            if (empty($results)) {
              return;
            }

            $csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_keys($results[0])).'";'."\n";;

            foreach ($results as $row) {
              $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"',$row).'";'."\n";
            }
            $csv_output .= "\n";
            $dir = "/home/modifoun/public_html/wp-content/plugins/schloarship/menu-pages/csv/";
            $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";

            header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
            header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
            header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
            print $csv_output;
            exit;
          //  echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>Data Written to CSV File. <a href='".$geturl."' download>Click Here to Download</a></div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: when I add this to function.php then it and calling this function in plugin page then it shows blank page

Answer (score 0):

The only thing is required is ob_start() and ob_end_clean()

Just after if(isset($_POST['export'])) use ob_start() and just before the closing braces of this if statement use ob_end_clean().

use below headers

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report.csv");

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Expires: 0");

Comment: if(isset($_POST['export']))
{  ob_start();
     $file = 'email_csv'; // ?? not defined in original code
         
          $dir = "/home/modifoun/public_html/wp-content/plugins/schloarship/menu-pages/csv/";
          $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";

         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$dir."Report.csv");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  ob_end_clean();
  exit();
} doing this but showing no error and no file is download

Comment: use only this below two headers only header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report.csv");

Comment: is it possible that if I want to save it on server

Comment: Last thing i want to try is place ob_start() above the if(isset($_POST['export'])) and ob_get_clean() just below the opening curly braces of if(isset($_POST['export'])). hope it should work'